# What is the Android Maven plugin?

Tags: android, maven, plugins, android-library

I can't really understand what exactly this Maven plugin does. 
Can someone explain to me what it does and how can this benefit my Android project?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Apache Maven is a software project management and comprehension tool.
>   Based on the concept of a project object model (POM), Maven can manage
>   a project's build, reporting and documentation from a central piece of
>   information.

[Visit Maven Website Here](http://maven.apache.org/)

You can read more about what maven is and how it is used in [this SO post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13335351/what-does-maven-do-in-theory-and-in-practice-when-is-it-worth-to-use-it)

One of the perks of using maven is that is will automatically download the latest version of a library for you.