# Eclipse package upgrade

Tags: eclipse

How do I upgrade a package in Eclipse?

Sorry, but google keeps wanting to tell me how to update the whole of eclipse.

I need to update aws-lambda-java-events version 1.3.0 to version 2.2.2 or even 2.2.4

Thanks

Comment: Help->Eclipse Marketplace check if the plugin is present for it

Comment: You need to manually update your `aws-lambda-java-events` package. The AWS Documentation page, [Building Lambda Functions with Java](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-programming-model.html), states: *"These libraries are available through the [Maven Central Repository](https://maven.apache.org/) and can also be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/)."* If you "download" from GitHub, then once you have the updated package you need to change either your Eclipse environment's Java build settings or your Eclipse project's build settings, to include the package.

Comment: If you're not sure what Maven is, there is a Stack Overflow question with an awesome answer that should shed some light: [What does Maven do, in theory and in practice? When is it worth to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13335351/what-does-maven-do-in-theory-and-in-practice-when-is-it-worth-to-use-it)

Comment: How did you add it there in the first place?