# How to import a package I found online in Java?

Tags: java, package

I am trying to use [this class](http://dhale.github.io/jtk/api/edu/mines/jtk/dsp/BandPassFilter.html), but i'm having trouble importing it into my code. Anyone know it's not allowing me to import it? It is giving me a "Cannot resolve symbol 'edu'"

Comment: Is the jar on your classpath?

Comment: How are you trying to import it? I have the slight idea you might not yet use a build tool like maven or gradle, so I'd suggest you look into one of them. They handle importing external libraries into your classpath much better than just downloading a jar and importing it by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find the details [here](https://github.com/dhale/jtk#using-the-mines-jtk)

---

You need to download the `.jar`from *https://search.maven.org/search?q=a:edu-mines-jtk*, and add to your classpath,

- on a IDE like IntelliJ : [Correct way to add external jars (lib/*.jar) to an IntelliJ IDEA project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-external-jars-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project)
- command line https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/10/5-ways-to-add-multiple-jar-to-classpath-java.html

Or use maven, and just add the dependency : [What does Maven do, in theory and in practice? When is it worth to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13335351/what-does-maven-do-in-theory-and-in-practice-when-is-it-worth-to-use-it)